# How to use II (or) in EL boolean expression

Tags: jsf, el, or-operator

I'd like to conditionally render a component like below:

```
rendered="#{att.attName != 'att1' or 'att2'}"
```

However, that didn't work. I have tried both `or` and `||`, but it evaluates only the left hand of OR condition, so in above case it compares only with `"att1"` not with `"att2"`

If I change the order then it compares with `"att2"` not with `"att1"`.

Comment: How would you do it in plain Java code? `if(att.getAttName() != "att1" || "att2")` Is that valid syntax? (ignoring the reference comparison)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be what you need

```
rendered="#{(att.attName != 'att1') and (att.attName != 'att2')}"
```

(brackets aren't needed, but I added them for readability)

Comment: Because you don't want it to be equal with `att1` AND also not with `att2`. Otherwise, it would always be `true`. Logical, isn't it? If you really want an OR, then use `#{!(att.attName == 'att1' or att.attName == 'att2')}`

Comment: so in my code it always compare with both value if first condition found true? rendered="#{att.attName != 'att1' or 'att2'}"

Comment: Uh no, it's simply invalid syntax. You're seeing `'att1' or 'att2'` as a whole. That's wrong. It are actually `att.attName != 'att1'` and `'att2'` which are individually being compared. Like as in normal Java (you're familiar with it?).